# Is there a way to run multiline Python scripts on the traditional interactive shell like shell plus?

Tags: python, django, command-line-interface

I have to run Python scripts on an old server that serves a `Django` app, every time I'm running the commands line by line, I want to be able to paste the script or set of commands all at once like shell plus `Django` extension, is there a way?
for example, I want to paste the code below all at once, like I do in Shell plus the `Django` extension.

```
fields = ['id', "name"]
rows = article_list
filename = "articles_with_highlighted_text_v2.csv"

with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    csvwriter.writerow(fields)
    csvwriter.writerows(rows)
```

I've tried a Google search but unfortunately haven't been able to find any tricks to be able to run the script all at once on the Python shell.

Thanks.